# Rails - Save model with or without raising error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im writing method where user set boolean to run save on records with or without raising errors.

```
Record.all.each do |record|
  if raise_bool.true?
    # save the record with raise error
  else
    # save the record no raise error
  end
end
```

But unsure how I can achieve, any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean "raise" an error or are you skipping validation. If a `save` fails validation the INSERT/UPDATE does not occur but it does not raise an error. I would assume you are looking for the former which would allow a user to truly save an otherwise invalid record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can raise errors with `save!` or you can return errors as a boolean with `save`.

In general, you always want to use `save!` If you think you do not want to use `save!` you should probably rethink what you are doing. Silencing errors in your code, especially when directly related to data will always cause issues in applications.

There's also an issue in the code with evaluating the boolean on each iteration of the record. You can do a cool thing with procs, to determine what to call outside the iteration:

```
method_save = raise_bool == true? ? proc { |x| x.save! } : proc { |x| x.save }
```

Then inside the loop:

```
method_save.call(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exactly answer your question, but let me suggest a similar approach that is more consistent with the "Rails way". Errors are raised (presumably) when validation fails. So consider making the validation conditional:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  attribute_accessors :user_declines_validations

  validates :name, presence: true, unless: user_declines_validations?

end
```

then you can do

```rb
MyModel.new(user_declines_validation?: false, name: nil)

MyModel.new(user_declines_validations?: true, name: 'Norm')
```